# Rails 3 Fixture Join Table Ids are Incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I am trying to work with fixtures in rails.  The rake db:fixtures:load runs without error, and table populates my data, but my many to many join table contains incorrect ids:

Example:

```
**tags.yml**
one:
  id: 1
  tag: pie
  posts: two

two:
  id: 2
  tag: cake
  posts: one, two

**posts.yml**
one:
  id: 1
  subject: subject
  content: content
  slug: woot
  tags: cake

two:
  id: 2
  subject: subject2
  content: content2
  slug: this_is_good
  tags: pie, cake
```

After running migrations and `db:fixtures:load` my tables get populated as:

tags:
id------tag
1 ...... pie
2 ...... cake

posts_tags:
rowid - post_id - tag_id
1 ...... 1 ...... 974324064
2 ...... 2 ...... 576189563
3 ...... 3 ...... 974324064

For some reason an auto-generated tag_id is getting created and being populated in my join table. Why?

**Edit**

The migrations are defined as:

```
  def self.up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

and

```
  def self.up
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :tag

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :posts_tags, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :tag_id
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have proper associations defined. You just need a small change in your fixtures:

```
**tags.yml**
one:
  tag: pie
  posts: two

two:
  tag: cake
  posts: one, two

**posts.yml**
one:
  subject: subject
  content: content
  slug: woot
  tags: 
    - two

two:
  subject: subject2
  content: content2
  slug: this_is_good
  tags: 
    - one
    - two
```

EDIT: I deleted all the IDs from fixtures. That generates correct references. But this isn't quite the correct answer.

Comment: Let me quickly try it out. Are you on Rails 3?

Comment: Also, what is the association like? (`habtm` or `hm through` ?)

Comment: Both Post and Tag are associated with HABTM

Comment: Wow so _that's_ how you specify HABTM relations in YAML for fixtures! I was afraid I would have to tediously define a fixture for the join table and match the ids up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume your models are something like this.

```
class Tag Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

That means the the posts_tags join table can only have post_id and tag_id in it as columns. It cannot have a rowid column. You'll need something like `:id => false` in the table definition of posts_tags.

Comment: the posts_tags table is already defined with:     create_table :posts_tags, :id => false do |t| t.integer :post_id t.integer tag_id end.  I don't know why the rowid column is getting created?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your test database has an old schema where you used a "rowid" column?

Try:

```
rake db:test:clone
```